# Multiple frames popping up when pressing a button

Tags: java, button

I am trying to create a user menu, that enables the user to chose diferent options, altought the program is openning the frames that i want, when i press the correct button, somehow after pressing button1 it pops up the same frame 2 times and keeps on doing that after pressing the next buttons.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Menu {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Maze");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300,200);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        JButton button1, button2;
        button1 = new JButton("Insert a File");
        button2 = new JButton("Generate");
        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);
        button1.addActionListener(new thehandler());
        button2.addActionListener(new thehandler2());

        thehandler handler = new thehandler();
        button1.addActionListener(handler);

        thehandler2 handler2 = new thehandler2();
        button2.addActionListener(handler2);

    }

    static class thehandler implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Select");
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame2.setSize(300,150);
            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            frame2.add(panel2);
            JButton button3, button4;
            button3 = new JButton("Solving");
            button4 = new JButton("Play");
            panel2.add(button3);
            panel2.add(button4);

            button3.addActionListener(new thehandler3());
            button4.addActionListener(new thehandler4());

            thehandler handler3 = new thehandler();
            button3.addActionListener(handler3);

            thehandler2 handler4 = new thehandler2();
            button4.addActionListener(handler4);

    }


    }

    static class thehandler3 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
            String stringInteger = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insert 
File: ", "Question", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }
    }

    static class thehandler4 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
            String stringInteger = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insert 
File: ", "Question", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }
    }

    static class thehandler2 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
            String stringInteger = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insert 
the size: ", "Question", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }
    }


}
```

That´s all the code i wrote so far.
[see the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duUH0.png)
I really don´t know why this is happening and would appreciate any suggestions to solve the problem.

Comment: Not multiple only two frames are popped up instead of one? isn't it?

Comment: it pops the same frame 2 times after clicking the next buttons again, i posted the code so everyone can se what´s happening since its hard to take a print of it

Comment: i answered the question, you are having some repetition of functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is might because of the fact that you are adding the same `ActionListener` twice on the `JButton` (Don't know why you are doing that). Now since `JButton` has two `ActionListener` although the same, therefore each click results in two frames.

```
    button1.addActionListener(new thehandler());
    button2.addActionListener(new thehandler2());

    //No need of below lines of codes, these are just repetition of above functionality
    /*thehandler handler = new thehandler(); 
    button1.addActionListener(handler);

    thehandler2 handler2 = new thehandler2();
    button2.addActionListener(handler2); */
```

You have to change this in exactly two places in your code where such repetition occurred.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the problem and i didn´t even saw it. The question is answered.

Comment: Your welcome, and do what you have to do when you are satisfied by the answer. :-)